# Meaning of "any one time"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Please help me with the exact meaning of the phrase **"any one time"** in the text below.

> You don't think he'd had a good look at me **any one time** and thought
> the original was even worse than that poor picture, so he backed off?
>
> <sub>"Casting away" by Alice Munro</sub>

I searched other forums and found out it means **"at any given moment"** but I think it's not true for this particular context, I think it means **"even for once"**. Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I changed the title and content by dropping **at** because according to snailplane's suggestion, **at** is not connected with **any one time** in this context.

Comment: It's [good look at me] and [any one time].  There's no *at* in the latter phrase.

Comment: @snailplane Ah thanks, When I searched for "any one time" I only got results for "at any one time" Then I thought may be this is just a twisted version of that.

Comment: @snailplane Please pardon me for bothering you again. Please tell me. Do you agree with Maulik? Do you have any idea what does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, in this context, *at any given moment* does not fit. Since the sentence is clear that he never had a good look at her, *at [her] any one time* means *in any given circumstances.*

> [at any one time](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/once) - under any circumstances.

Comment: Thank you Maulik :) I don't know why I didn't find this definition before but I am surprised to see it's used for describing "once" while it could also mean "even for once". I think they are completely opposite of each other.

Comment: @GATA The author probably means *he, under any circumstances, gave no good look to her.*