# meaning of the phrase "at any one time" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> As I mentioned in the eating section, 7 to 14 days of a keto run is the most I would suggest **at any one time**.

Does the author mean *always* by that?

Comment: [Probably related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18492/meaning-of-any-one-time)

Answer (score 1):

No, it means "in one go". In other words, do keto for a maximum run of 7-14 days, then stop for a while before going back to it.

Comment: Why didn't the author just say "at a time"? What does "any" mean there?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope The use of *any* emphasizes repetition and the fact that one particular time is no different than another time. The same thing applies to them all equally. Think of *any one time* as combining *one time* and *any time*.